# Changing image's pixel values by using QSlider in Qt

Tags: image, qt

I am new at programming Qt.I have a Gui. It has slider and button. Also I can

get image as input and put it to a second label. The thing that I cannot do

getting pixels of image and change them with respect to the slider value.

Comment: Post some code showing us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef UI_TEST_H
#define UI_TEST_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenu>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QProgressBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QSlider>
#include <QtWidgets/QSplitter>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QToolBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_TestClass
{
public:
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QPushButton *pushButton;
    QSplitter *splitter;
    QSlider *slider;
    QProgressBar *progressBar;
    QMenuBar *menuBar;
    QMenu *menuTest;
    QToolBar *mainToolBar;
    QStatusBar *statusBar;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *TestClass)
    {
        if (TestClass->objectName().isEmpty())
            TestClass->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("TestClass"));
        TestClass->resize(528, 400);
        centralWidget = new QWidget(TestClass);
        centralWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("centralWidget"));
        pushButton = new QPushButton(centralWidget);
        pushButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton"));
        pushButton->setGeometry(QRect(50, 230, 75, 23));
        splitter = new QSplitter(centralWidget);
        splitter->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("splitter"));
        splitter->setGeometry(QRect(40, 110, 241, 43));
        splitter->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
        slider = new QSlider(splitter);
        slider->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("slide"));
        slider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
        splitter->addWidget(slider);
        progressBar = new QProgressBar(splitter);
        progressBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("progressBar"));
        progressBar->setValue(24);
        splitter->addWidget(progressBar);
        TestClass->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
        menuBar = new QMenuBar(TestClass);
        menuBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("menuBar"));
        menuBar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 528, 21));
        menuTest = new QMenu(menuBar);
        menuTest->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("menuTest"));
        TestClass->setMenuBar(menuBar);
        mainToolBar = new QToolBar(TestClass);
        mainToolBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("mainToolBar"));
        TestClass->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mainToolBar);
        statusBar = new QStatusBar(TestClass);
        statusBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("statusBar"));
        TestClass->setStatusBar(statusBar);

        menuBar->addAction(menuTest->menuAction());

        retranslateUi(TestClass);
        QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), progressBar, SLOT(setValue(int)));

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(TestClass);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *TestClass)
    {
        TestClass->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("TestClass", "Test", 0));
        pushButton->setText(QApplication::translate("TestClass", "Button", 0));
        menuTest->setTitle(QApplication::translate("TestClass", "Test", 0));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class TestClass: public Ui_TestClass {};
} /
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "test.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtGui>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Test w;
    w.show();

    QImage myImage;
    myImage.load("Baboon.bmp");
    QLabel myLabel;
    myLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));

    myLabel.show();




    return a.exec();
}
```